# Permission Denied when using Scalpel

Tags: mount, iphone

I've mounted my iphone to `/home/user1/iphone` using ifuse. Now I would like to use the tool Scalpel on the directory, but when running the command I get this:

```
ERROR: Couldn't open input file: -- Permission denied
Scalpel was unable to open the image file: /home/user1/iphone
Skipping...
```

This happens when running with `sudo` as well. Found no solution yet, any ideas?

Comment: Use the `mount` command to see how it's actually mounted. Explore your permission/ownership problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld A `bash` script to answer "Why can't I Read/Write that file?"..

Answer (score 0):

Scalpel expects to access a single file that contains a disk image, not a mounted directory. You would first need to extract the complete disk image from the iPhone using some recovery/forensic tool.

Through iFuse, you will only see files and directories that exist according to the phone's filesystem - you can't look into the "unallocated space".

iFuse access is like accessing a Windows or NFS disk share: the system that actually contains the data controls what the clients will be able to see. In a recovery scenario, you'll need full access to the storage medium (or an exact byte-for-byte copy of it, i.e. a disk image) so that the recovery/forensic tool can examine the actual contents of what the filesystem metadata says is "unallocated space".